# PyCharm 3.4 CE: Remote host access plugin

Tags: remote-access, pycharm

JetBrains.com says:

> Synchronization with servers, uploading, downloading, and managing files on them are provided via the Remote Hosts Access bundled plugin, which is by default enabled. If not, activate it in the Plugins page of the Settings dialog box.

I don't have Remote Hosts Access in Projects Settings/Plugins:
[image: projects settings]

What should i do to install it? It is also absent in "Browse repositories" window list.

May be i should install it via External tools, but how?

Comment: I suspect that CE doesnt support this plugin. Prof.ed. supports.

Answer (score 3):

Remote Hosts Access bundled plugin is not present in newer versions. Try Source synchronizer. It does the same. It supports SCP, FTP, SFTP protocols.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7374?pr=idea_ce

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), "FTP/SFTP/FTPS remote host deployment" is indeed "Supported only in Professional Edition".